# How do I do custom model data parsing in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

While using backbone to hit an api, I've found that I need to only include some of the data in the response.  The webserver is giving me back metadata in addition to data concerning my objects that I don't need.

The following solution works, but doesn't feel right.  Is there a standard way of doing this?

```
var accountsCollection = new AccountsCollection();

accountsCollection.fetch({success : function(collection){
    var results = new AccountsCollection();
    collection.each(function(item){
        results.add(new AccountModel({
            id: item.toJSON().result[0].id,
            messageText: item.toJSON().messageText,
            address1: item.toJSON().result[0].address1,
            address2: item.toJSON().result[0].address2
        }));
    });

    onDataHandler(results);
}});
```

EDIT:  This was my final solution based on the accepted answer:

```
    parse: function(response) {
        var accounts = [];
        _.each(response['result'], function (account) {
            accounts.push(account);
        });
        return accounts;
    }
```

Comment: why not just ignore the unneeded data? far cleaner and it's not like you're saving any processing with the above.

Comment: @MBHNYC It's not cleaner because when I call save it will try to persist that stuff, and also I have to write .result[0] before every field in my templates, and anywhere else I try to work with my model.  It clutters up the entire application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try overriding the [`Backbone.Collection.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method and do some crazy underscore stuff. No idea if it fits your data..

```
var keysILike = ['foo', 'bar'];

AccountsCollection.extend({
  parse: function(response) {
    return _.compact(_.flatten(_.map(response, function (model) {
      var tmp = {};
      _.each(_.keys(model), function (key) {
        if (_.contains(keysILike, key)) tmp[key] = model[key];
      })
      return tmp;
    })));
  }
});
```

---

With respect to @Sushanth's awesomeness you definitely want to use this solution:

```
var keysILike = ['foo', 'bar'];

AccountsCollection.extend({
  parse: function(response) {
    _.each(response, function (model) {
      _.each(_.keys(model), function (key) {
        if (!_.contains(keysILike, key)) delete model[key]
      })
    });
    return response;
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 .. This is a better idea than the hacky approach OP was trying.. Also You can avoid an extra object to store all the link keys.. Instead just delete the data from the response object.. `if (!_.contains(keysILike, key)) delete response[key];` And just return response

Comment: @cr0.. You are welcome. But that was an addition to the code you have already written ;)

Comment: @Sushanth  Your answers were very helpful for understanding the right approach to the problem.  I've posted my final solution as an edit.  Thanks to both of you!